# Loggly: Unable to receive logs from NodeJs with Winston

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, loggly

I configured everything regarding the [documentation's page](https://www.loggly.com/docs/node-js-logs/).

I get no error from my Node app, however I don't receive any log on loggy from my app.
I can't figure out where does the problem come from.

My code in config.js:

```
var winston  = require('winston');
require('winston-loggly-bulk');

winston.add(winston.transports.Loggly, {
    inputToken: "aToken",
    subdomain: "aSubDomain",
    tags: ["Winston-NodeJS"],
    json:true
});

winston.log('info',"Hello World from Node.js!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks fine. Did you check you are using the right token from https://YourSubdomain.loggly.com/tokens not from https://YourSubdomain.loggly.com/account/users/api/tokens? The use of both the tokens are different so this could be a reason that you are not seeing any log in your account.